# Application of Euler Theorem On homogeneous function in two variables.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Euler theorem says,

If
$$u=f(x,y)\text{  ,homogeneous}$$
Then,$$x\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=nu$$
Where $$n\to \text{degree of function}$$
Question

If
$$u=u_1+u_2+u_3$$
then$$x\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=(x\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial y})+(x\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial y})+(x\frac{\partial u_3}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial u_3}{\partial y})$$
$$nu=n_1u_1+n_2u_2+n_3u_3$$
is it possible to apply the theorem like this.

Answer (score 1):

one way to see the problem with your assumed form is to note that you would need :
$$
nu =n(u_1+u_2+u_3) \\
=n_1u_1+n_2u_2+n_3u_3
$$
so 
$$
\sum_{j=1}^3(n-n_j)u_j = 0
$$

Comment: So can we apply the theorem like this

Comment: if the $u_j$ are linearly independent this forces $n_1=n_2=n_3=n$